# react native error only when I am not in debug mode .json()

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, http, react-native

I have very much code so it is complicated to describe my problem. I just put the code here where the error is.

If i am in debug mode everything works perfectly. But if I disable debug mode i get the error "undefined is not a object (evaluating 'b.svcResL[0].res)".

I get the error when I call  res.json()
How can i find the problem when it works in debug mode but in normal mode not?

```
 return fetch(url, req)
        .then((res) => {
            err.statusCode = res.status
            if (!res.ok) {
                err.message = res.statusText
                throw err
            }
            console.log('============that goes========================');
            console.log(res);
            console.log('====================================');

            return res.json()
        })
        .then((b) => {
            console.log('=============here is error=======================');
            console.log(b);
            console.log('====================================');
            const d = b.svcResL[0].res
            const c = d.common || {}

            if (Array.isArray(c.remL)) {
                d.remarks = c.remL.map(rem => profile.parseRemark(profile, rem))
            }
            if (Array.isArray(c.opL)) {
                d.operators = c.opL.map(op => profile.parseOperator(profile, op))
            }
            if (Array.isArray(c.prodL)) {
                const parse = profile.parseLine(profile, d.operators)
                d.lines = c.prodL.map(parse)
            }
            if (Array.isArray(c.locL)) {
                const parse = loc => profile.parseLocation(profile, loc, d.lines)
                d.locations = c.locL.map(parse)
            }
            return d
        })
```

Comment: `b.svcResL[0]` is `undefined` - what is the value of `b`?

Comment: b is  the response

Comment: What is printed after `====here is error====`?

Comment: in debug mode everything works perfekt and i see the response. When i am not in debug mode i cant see what was logged there

Comment: What is the value of `b` when you are in debug mode?

Comment: an object with a lot of informations. b.svgResL [0] is there not undefined.